# Problem with URL path and .htacces redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

which redirects all traffic to `HTTPS` and `non-www`, perfectly. However if a user happens to visit a page on the website and includes `www` it doesn't keep the full path but redirects to the home page. For example:

`www.example.com` goes to `example.com`

but

`www.example.com/page` goes to `example.com` instead of `example.com/page`

this happens regardless of using HTTPS or HTTP. It's something to do with the `www` redirect that's causing the problem (?)... I just can't figure it out and I've googled many answers to no avail.

***UPDATE***

My full `.htacces` is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ index.php [L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
# except for requests to plugin assets files
RewriteRule ^assets/plugins/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_%=]+)/(.*)$ site/plugins/$1/assets/$2 [L,N]
RewriteCond $1 !^plugins/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_%=]+/assets/.*
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) index.php [L]

# block direct access to kirby and the panel sources
RewriteRule ^(kirby|panel\/app|panel\/tests)/(.*) index.php [L]

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

# HTTP to HTTPS and WWW to non WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Please keep these rules above all of your rules and make sure you clear your browser cache before testing these.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For www requests changing to https.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

##For non-www requests changing to https.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```